# Linq Convert anonymous to entity object by select

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

```
var reassignForms = _formQueryRepository.WithRelatedEntities()
            .Where(x => x.Id == formId && x.SchoolId == schoolId)
            .Select(y => y.FormUsers.Where(m => m.CanEdit).Select(z => new ReassignFormDTO
            {
                Name = z.UserProfile.FullName,
                Id = z.UserProfile.Id,
                Email = z.UserProfile.Email,
                Role = z.UserProfile.UserRole,


            }));
```

I want to convert it to `ReassignFormDTO` but somehow it is returning an object which I cannot convert. I want this to be direct object not [0].objects.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `SelectMany`, change the first `Select` to `SelectMay` the result will be a list of `ReassignFormDTO`

Comment: `.SelectMany(y =>`

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on using  .SelectMany(y =>

Comment: The count is 2.  So the top level is a single item while the 2nd level is an array.  Because you have two selects you need to use SelectMany to reduce the levels from 2 to 1.

Comment: @SunilSingh please share the complete code sample and expected result, which others can reproduce

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
Maybe not all of your FormUsers are initialized? Try:
.SelectMany(y => y.FormUsers?.Where(...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.FirstOrDefault()` then it will return the first entity from the linq query. According to the debug window you have two `ReassignFormDTO` objects and seems like you would like to get only one.

Please provide more detail, so we can help more. Not sure if my previous answer will help you.

EDIT: I didn't noticed the second select inside you statement. According to the comments `.SelectMany(z => z)` should help you out.